# coloring specific bars in grouped barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a grouped bar plot. I would like to color the bars which is >=1 and leave the rest of the bars as unfilled. How can I do that?

Here is my code

```
data = read.csv ("/home/paul/Desktop/dataset.csv")  
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df.long<-melt(data)
df.long$names <- factor(df.long$names, levels=unique(df.long$names))
ggplot(df.long,aes(x=names,y=value,fill=variable))+ labs(x = "x", y = "y" ) + ylim(0, 2)  + 
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
scale_fill_hue(l=40) + 
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14), axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))
```

My data

```
names   d1  d2
E1  1.30    1.27
K2  1.05    1.86
D4  0.94    1.51
E2  1.01    1.62
N1  1.17    1.47
Q3  1.22    1.51
S7  1.00    1.24
G2  0.78    0.96
H5  1.04    1.04
T1  1.04    1.14
A5  0.71    0.71
P4  1.03    1.27
Y2  1.34    0.58
V4  0.83    0.50
M3  1.02    0.53
C7  0.98    0.31
```

Comment: Add a variable `isColored` to your dataframe which is == 1 if you want to color the item, and use `color = isColored` or `fill = isColored` in your `aes`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the fill criteria in the `fill` argument of `aes()`, and set the manual fill colours to be NA for those you don't want filled

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(names = letters[1:10],
                 d1 = runif(10, 0, 2),
                 d2 = runif(10, 0, 2))

## using a manual scale
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=names, y=d1, fill=(d1 >= 1))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "steelblue"))
```

[image]